# Jquery included library

Tags: jquery, css

Me again with simple questions. I was searching for jquery code which does: click WHOLE tr to show/hide other tr (which in my case is .none). Finally managed to find one and it's working fine, but only on JSfiddle. So my guess I include wrong jquery library, but I can't figure out which one I need to include to make this code work.

Code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gwf4uab/

Jquery I include in header:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank You in advance!

Comment: Show your HTML code where you include libraries.

Comment: View the errorconsole in your browser to see if any errors are shown

Comment: You need to wrap your code in [document-ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Thanks for answers guys, it seems I'm not classifed to be newbie yet, I'm wanna be newbie :D Well anyways thanks for solving my problem Satpal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is incomplete but may be the reason will be :

You have not inlcuded your jQuery code inside document.ready function try this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('tr:not(.none)').click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr:not(.none)').toggle();
  });


});
```

OR

you have writen your code before jQuery library is loaded so your complete code should be -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $('tr:not(.none)').click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('tr:not(.none)').toggle();
      });


    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. It seems I need to read more about jquery basics.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your jquery script with :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Put your javascript code here...


});
```